# Omit one value from a range

Tags: python, range, idioms

What's the most concise way in Python to write a range (generator or list) which omits one single value. So given integers `n`and `k` with `0`≤`k`<`n` I want all the integers from `0` (inclusive) to `n` (exclusive) but without `k`.

Comment: Is there some reason you need the shortest way to write this in Python?

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: Just curious. So don't consider this as a strict optimum in the sense of code golf; it has to remain practical, somwhat readable, fit for everyday use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your list runs from 0 to n, we know that for all values `n` in the list `ns`, `ns.index(n) == n`. (`ns[0] == 0`, `ns[1] == 1`, and so on.)

With that in mind, you could slice your list in this way:

```
ns = range(n)
ms = ns[:k] + ns[k+1:]
```

Arguably shorter, but also arguably less clear, so up to you!

Answer (score 2):

The shortest solution I have found so far is

```
[i for i in range(n) if i != k]
```

But perhaps there is something shorter. And a problem here is that in Python 2 the variable `i` bleeds into the surrounding scope, which can be annoying in some cases.

Comment: _"perhaps there is something shorter."_ Yes, there's `[i for i in range(n)if i!=k]` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Slightly shorter than the list comprehension solution:

```
sorted(set(range(n))-{k})
```

... But probably not as fast or comprehensible, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result to again be a generator:

```
filter(k.__ne__, range(n))
```

(One character longer than [Kevin's set operation approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24367739/674064), but probably more memory efficient and maybe also with better performance. Also, IMHO, a better semantic fit to the task at hand. On the other hand, accessing the low-level-ish `.__ne__` might violate the "somewhat readable" goal, depending on the audience.)